# Is there a bsearch that returns the index rather than the value?

Tags: ruby, bsearch

Ruby's `Array#bsearch` assumes a sorted array, takes a block returning true/false, and uses a binary search to find the first element for which the block returns true.  For example:

```
ary = [0, 4, 7, 10, 12]
ary.bsearch {|x| x >=   4 } #=> 4
```

I want a version that also uses binary search, but returns the index of the found value, rather than the value itself.  In the above example, it would return `1`.

I was not able to find any such built in method -- is there one?  If not, are there any other builtins I could use to achieve this?  Alternatively, does ruby have any built in structures that support both search and insert in `n log n` time?

Comment: You could try something like ``ary.index(ary.bsearch { |x| x >= 4 })``

Comment: @Piccolo, your suggestion will be O(n), not O(n log n).